# firebase authentication with facebook - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, fbsdk

Im trying to access my react native app through facebook login. I'm using fbsdk and firebase on android. Here´s my function:

```
loginConFacebookHandler = () => {
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'])
.then(result => {
  if (result.isCancelled) {
    console.log('Cancelado')
    return Promise.reject(new Error('The user cancelled the request'));
  }
  console.log(`Login success with permissions: ${result.grantedPermissions.toString()}`);
  return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
})
.then(data => {
  const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);      
  return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
})
.then(currentUser => {
  console.log(`Facebook Login with user : ${JSON.stringify(currentUser.toJSON())}`);
  () => {startMainTabs()}
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Login con facebook falló con error: ${error}`);
})
```

}

where startMainTabs() redirects to another screen. It works perfectly when I log in with user and password:

```
loginUsuarioYContraseñaHandler = (email, password) => {
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(() => {startMainTabs()})
.catch(error => {alert(error)})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your are not waiting for the response, your need to make a sync function and  then navigate to the other screen, this is an example that i used in another application, hope you cant use it.

```
export async function facebookLogin() {
let response;
try {
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
    if (result.isCancelled) {
        response = "El usuario cancelo el inicio de sesion"
    } else {
        const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (!data) {
            response = "Hubo un error obteniendo los datos, cheque su internet";
        } else {
            const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
            await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then((user) => {
                response = user;
            });
        }
    }
    return response;
} catch (e) {
    response = (e.toString() === " An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.") ? "Usuario existente con el mismo coreo, intente con otro." : e.toString();
    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: Your problem is at redirercting or at navigatin to your other screen? Make sure u set up your configuration to your facebook application and you do all the steps listed here. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)